# How to get my dog back?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I died in Minecraft, after I respawned at my bed, I went back to get my stuff. My dog was there but he didn't follow me or did not listen to my commands to stand. How do I get my dog back?

Comment: That sounds like a bug. Which version are you playing in?

Comment: Quick fix: don't die

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try closeing the app, and coming back into the world. Sometimes my game lags, so I just close the app or go out of the world. It’s usually fixed by the time I go back in. :)